# Denying anonymous users in asp.net query string problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

in my current Asp.net application i'm trying to make anonymous user go directly to my login page i have tried following code in my web.config file.

```
  <system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms" >
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

but if i run the application i get the following error:
[IIS error after running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAEqS.png).
I already tried increasing the query string length but it doesn't work.

thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow anonymous on your Account/Login method. As you can see in the URL, you are getting stuck in an infinite loop (Login method triggers redirect to Account/Login because you have `<deny users="?"/>` set globally).